# Create directions on a map based on custom data

Tags: dictionary, overlay, routes, directions

So what I'm trying to do is the following:

1. Have a map (such as Google Maps or questMaps). It doesn't matter at all which API I need to use.
2. On that map have an overlay on the streets. So say (for example) the street has bad lightning at night, it will be colored red. If it has good lightning it will have a green overlay.
3. Based on the overlay the map creates a custom route (for example the user only wants to walk on the green/well lit streets).

I have no idea how to accomplish this (especially step 3).

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll have to decide what data you need.  How do you categorize certain streets as lit or unlit?  What if some parts of a street are well lit and some have no lights?  Do you need to know the location of every streetlight in your area?  What if lights burn out?

After figuring out what data you need, you need to build your dataset.  I'd be VERY surprised if this data already exists, so you will probably need to gather it yourself.  Either go around town and take notes, or crowdsource the project, or figure out some other way.

Once you have gathered your data, learn the drawing API of whatever mapping tool you wish to use.  They all should have functions in their API for drawing colored lines (for streets) or points (for streetlights) on top of an existing map.

Finally, learn the navigational API of the mapping tool you chose.  You're right, this is a hard step.  I know Google Maps lets you specify certain waypoints when requesting directions; maybe your app can calculate well-lit waypoints and feed them to Google Maps' Directions service to influence the route it generates.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much. The waypoint idea is a breakthrough for me.

Comment: glad I could help.  If this was useful to you, please consider upvoting and/or accepting it as a good answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 0):

For custom routing, you need to read up on "Graph Theory". This ignores the geography of the street map, and considers it as a set of junctions (nodes or vertices in the graph theory jargon) connected by edges. You can assign weights to edges - these could be lengths, travel times, ones and zeroes etc. Anything. They can have no relation to the position on the map.

So for your application, you'd assign a large weight to unlit streets, and a small weight to lit streets, then use a standard minimum-weight algorithm to get a route from one node to another.